# How to animate conditionally-rendered components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-motion

I'm trying to use [React Motion UI Pack](https://github.com/souporserious/react-motion-ui-pack) to animate the slide-in/slide-out animation for my Side Navigation. This is it:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isThere: false,
    showOverlay: false
  } 
  this.updatePredicate = this.updatePredicate.bind(this);
  this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
  this.handleOverlayClick = this.handleOverlayClick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updatePredicate();
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updatePredicate);
}

updatePredicate() {
  this.setState({ isThere: window.innerWidth > this.props.breakWidth })
}

handleToggleClick(){
  this.setState({
    isThere: true,
    showOverlay: true
  })
}

handleOverlayClick(){
  this.setState({
    isThere: false,
    showOverlay: false
  });
}

let sidenav = (
  <Tag {...attributes} className={classes} key="sidenav">
    <ul className="custom-scrollbar">
      {src &&
        <li>
          <div className="logo-wrapper">
            <a href={href}>
              <img src={src} className="img-fluid"/>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      }
      {children}
    </ul>
  </Tag>
);

return (
  <div>
    { isThere ? (
      <Transition
      component={false}
      appear={{ opacity: 0.2, translateX: -300 }}
      enter={{ opacity: 1, translateX: 0 }}
      leave={{ opacity: 0.2, translateX: -300 }}
    >
        { sidenav }
      </Transition>
      ) : (
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleToggleClick} key="sideNavToggles">ClickMe</Button>
      ) }
    {showOverlay && (
      <div id="sidenav-overlay" onClick={this.handleOverlayClick} key="overlay"></div>
    )}
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The utility seems awesome, yet there is something I cannot wrap my head around. My component renders button or the sidenav depending on the `breakWith` prop. Clicking on the rendered button causes the SideNav to slide-in anyway, this time together with an overlay. `Transition` allowed for a smooth slide-in animation, but now I would like to apply a slide-out one upon clicking on the overlay.

Few hours passed and I'm starting to think it is impossible. Rendering of components is conditional & state-based (the `isThere ? (...` part in `render()`), right? As the pack offers no `willLeave` props, there seems to be no time to animate the `leave` in between the change of state and the re-render with the conditionally-rendered element already missing.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sup guys, found this seemingly related [issue](https://github.com/souporserious/react-motion-ui-pack/issues/66). Will try it out, post 'em results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes - the answer found [here](https://github.com/souporserious/react-motion-ui-pack/issues/66) effectively addresses the problem. To solve it, I moved the *conditional* logic of the component **up**, created appropriate variable, and encapsulated it inside a `<Transition>` in `render()`. If there is a lesson to be learned here, it is that `<Transition>` from [Reakt Motion UI Pack](https://github.com/souporserious/react-motion-ui-pack) (and, perhaps, elsewhere) does not fire its `leave` animation if surrounded by a conditional statement, making it impossible to use it together with `ternary operator` if you don't want the `false` component to be animated as well.